# How to make activity with n buttons same size using RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need do design programatically one activity with 6 buttons (same size h and w), and all buttons show a fullsize of activity.

I tried do this: [RelativeLayout with buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343299/relativelayout-with-buttons) and modify for tests.

Show one button!!! 
`

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main);      

    ArrayList<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
    //RelativeLayout bg = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.layout.main);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Button newButton = new Button(this);
        newButton.setId(100 + i + 1); // ID of zero will not work
        newButton.setText("XXXX");
        buttons.add(newButton);
        // New layout params for each button
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        if (i > 0) {
            // using getId() here in case you change how you assign IDs
            int id = buttons.get(i - 1).getId();
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, id);
        }
        this.addContentView(newButton, lp);
    }`
```

please look this line if ok: **this.addContentView(newButton, lp);**

Thanks!!!

mateus

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit not clear from your question whether you want all buttons to distribute evenly across the activity space or each button to take over all activity space?

In first case what you need is a LinearLayout with layout_weight for buttons set to 1.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.weight = 1;
```

In the second case I think it's better to use a FrameLayout and just let buttons take over all space by setting

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT
```

to both dimensions.